# How to configure console to actually run Controller or Model methods from it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Yes, I have checked other posts at SO regarding how to call controller or MOdel methods from the control and they mentioned the following:

```
foo = ActionController::Base::ApplicationController.new
foo.some_method
```

that is, creating an instance and then calling the method. But if I write just that either on my linux console, it just says:

```
bash: =: command not found
```

and if I do the same from Nitrous I get the same reply.

I can also see at RailsCasts how the author just writes the name of the Model dot and method name and it gets running but that will echo a command not found in my console. My Model is called Article so Article.fetchstuff will not work.

```
http://railscasts.com/episodes/168-feed-parsing?autoplay=true
```

from my console I can get other commands running like

```
rails s, rails generate controller, rails runner
```

etc, but that is all.

I have also read about something like:

```
$ ./script
```

but doing it that it reads command not found and if at Nitrous I write: 
script, it echoes,

```
script started
```

so I must be trying to execute all those commands from the wrong place, but don't know what else to do.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand that right. But it seems you try to run Rails/Ruby commands from your bash console. To do the above you have to start `rails console` and then you can issue the commands

Comment: put it in the answer and I will check it as that. I had tried that before too and maybe did not realize that I was that close. I have done rails console then I am taken to a different promt so I issued foo = ArticleController.new and got a series of echoes sort of @action_has_layout= true etc so then I had created a test method to puts hi and did foo.test reply was wrong number of arguments, but you actually answered the right question, so post it there and I will approve it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to make it work :-)

```
$ rails console
> foo = ApplicationController.new
```

You can then check the methods available with

```
> foo.methods
```

The public methods you can list with

```
> foo.public_methods
```

Then you can call the method you want to call, e.g.

```
> foo.formats
=> [:html, :text, :js, :css, ...]
```

Is that what you try to do?

Comment: @patricio ... You have to call it as you've defined it, which we don't know. That said, running controller methods like this seems... Wonky. If they're standalone methods they probably don't belong in the controller in the first place.

Comment: yes, yes, got it, the IDE put me parentheses by default and therefore the call expected an argument, now it works. Thank you everybody. yes, the test method does not belong to the controller, but it did its job, to prove me that I can call them by printing a word

Comment: @patricio ... I downvoted your question because how to use the Rails console is covered in the Rails documentation and tutorials, and IMO it should be fairly obvious that running Ruby code from a regular shell would never work. Lashing out, calling names, and thinking you know anything about people who downvote on SO is counter-productive; people downvote for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @patricio You insist on being rude and combative; this confuses me. I'm not out of a job, and running Ruby code from a regular shell prompt is nonsensical--most shells aren't Ruby. I didn't downvote based on my perception of your intelligence, I downvoted because even cursory glances at docs and tutorials would have answered this question. Downvotes are commentary on questions, not the questioners. It's too bad you're so angry about something so silly; I'm sorry SO's philosophy is so strongly opposed to your own.

Comment: not accepted. I clearly mentioned that I had gone through the rails console, yet the output was not clear to me. There was other guy, with another personality who helped me out and made no issue of it and he solved the question. He had 132 points, yet you, over 110.000 are pissing me off, leave me alone for once please.

Answer (score 0):

I think the part that was confusing about the question was that you were asking about how to run from the console, which many of us would have assumed you were referring to the rails console and not just your terminal shell (i.e. bash).  Rails is designed to be run as an application and the console is generally used for debugging and/or testing out code ideas. [Sugaryourcoffee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2421215/sugaryourcoffee)'s answer seems pretty straightforward.  You must first start a rails console from your terminal with

```
rails c
```

or

```
rails console
```

Once your inside your rails console you can run methods sugaryourcoffee described.  One thing to bear in mind, you won't be able to call private methods directly.  Of course you must be in your application root directory before running `rails console`.